# Unable to install latest LTS / GRUB2 install issue

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I currently have 12.04 LTS installed and was trying to update to 16.04.4 LTS however I got myself in a bit of mire :(.

1. I created a bootable USB containing 16.04.4 LTS and installation was going great until the end when I got hit with an error message `grub-efi-amd64 package failed to install...`
2. I repeated above and obtained same error however in doing so I added another partition to my disk resulting in 2 copies of 16.04.4 getting written.
3. I have checked some answers and tried some stuff to resolve without success
4. Booted from USB and ran try Ubuntu & installed/ran boot_repair and generated a [boot-info file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PGsNzNH3Qw)
5. I then tried to run Gparted to remove the last installation of 16.04.4 - so deleted sda6 partition.
6. Reran boot-repair to get [boot-info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PbCmH4Wczc)
7. The file has some comments about what needs done - looking for sanity check before I commit to running boot-repair in repair mode

I checked system BIOS settings and boot order defined for both UEFI & Legacy support / Legacy support enabled & secure boot disabled
If any other information is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few more things

1. Used Gparted to delete all partitions with 16.04.4 LTS
2. Read that this issue could be resolved if I booted from CD, so burned a DVD and tried to install. As per USB all well except the same boot error messages.
3. Repeated #1 above and then tried using USB boot and selected the option to update 12.04 to 16.04.4 - still got the boot error except this time system completely broke and I was unable to login.
4. Final attempt was to go for the complete disk erase prior to install - this worked cleanly - so just need to perform a restore of information created using Aptik before I started to perform updates.

So it took a while but I think issues are now all resolved.